# Selenium Webdriver -dragAndDrop not working in Firefox 32

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, drag-and-drop, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do a simple drag and drop operation.Doesnt know why its not happenening.
I am using Selenium StandAlone Server 2.43.1 and firefox 32.

Below is my code:

```
@Before    
public void setUp() throws Exception {            
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();    
    baseUrl = "http://html5demos.com/drag";    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();    
  }

@Test
public void testdragAndDrop() throws Exception {    
    driver.get(baseUrl);    

    WebElement From=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/article/ul/li[3]/a"));    
    System.out.println(From.isDisplayed());     

    WebElement To=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/article/div"));    
      System.out.println(To.getTagName());     
      System.out.println(To.isEnabled());     
    Actions obj=new Actions(driver);    
    Action dragAndDrop= obj.clickAndHold(From)    
                           .moveToElement(To)    
                           .release(To)    
                           .build();    
    dragAndDrop.perform();    
    Thread.sleep(5000);    
}
```

I also tried running:

```
obj.dragAndDrop(From, To).build().perform();
```

Still same results..

Can anyone kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try using a more unique Xpath or Attribute for the Drag-gable elements, try this also hope it helps

```
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

        actions.clickAndHold(widget).moveToElement(dragHandler).build().perform();      
        actions.release(dragHandler).perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem at it was solved by enabling native events:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();    
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);    
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```